# Importing Angular 1.6 with Webpack 2.2

Tags: angularjs, webpack-2

In my entry file I am trying to import Angular 1.6 as a module:

```
import angular from '../../node_modules/angular/angular';
```

I then create my Angular module in the usual way:

```
angular.module('myModule', []);
```

When Webpack builds the project, it does include Angular in the generated bundle, but when I view the project in a browser, I see the message:

> Uncaught TypeError: _angular2.default.module is not a function

However, in the browser's dev tools, if I watch the `angular` variable, I can see that it does resolve to the Angular object, which has a `module` method.

I suspect the line that creates the module is being hit before Webpack finishes loading the module. Shouldn't Webpack wait for the module being imported to load before it executes the rest of the file?

How can I delay execution until the dependency (Angular) has loaded?

Comment: You wrote it's all in the same bundle, so everything is loaded at once. _"if I watch the angular variable"_ That's most likely the global variable, that still exists. With a proper setup it's `import angular from "angular".

Comment: I think an alias is required to `import angular from "angular"`? If I `import '../../node_modules/angular/angular';` then I see no script errors and my app works, but I want to get away from the global angular, and use imported angular

Comment: No alias required. I have `resolve: {  modules: ["node_modules", ...] }` and it works. The angular directory has an `index.js`, so `../../node_modules/angular` should work anyway.

Comment: I bow to you sir! That fixed it. Thanks